# How do I render an array using javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, html, canvas, rendering

I am currently building a replication of Atari's breakout for university. I currently have a working ball, a paddle and (potentially) some bricks. At the minute, the bricks are rendering incorrectly as the canvas remains blank at run-time. Could anyone please tell me where I'm going wrong (either with the 'bricks' variable or with the bricks section of the render function). The code is below:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("breakout");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var PADDLE_WIDTH_PX = canvas.width / 5;
var PADDLE_HEIGHT_PX = 10;
var PADDLE_SPEED = 450;

var ball = {
  x: canvas.width / 2,   //pixels
  y: canvas.height / 2,  //pixels
  xSpeed: 500,           //pixels per second
  ySpeed: 500,           //pixels per second
  radius: 100  //pixels
}

var paddle = {
//radius: 5,
/*speed: 500,
TopRight: ctx.moveTo(canvas.width / 1.35, canvas.height - (canvas.height / 12.5)),
TopSide: ctx.lineTo(canvas.width / 2, canvas.height - (canvas.height / 12.5)),
RightSide: ctx.lineTo(canvas.width / 1.35, canvas.height - (canvas.height / 27.5)),
BottomLeft: ctx.moveTo(canvas.width / 2, canvas.height - (canvas.height / 27.5)),
LeftSide: ctx.lineTo(canvas.width / 2, canvas.height - (canvas.height / 12.5)),
BottomSide: ctx.lineTo(canvas.width / 1.35, canvas.height - (canvas.height / 27.5))*/
xSpeed: 450,
x: (canvas.width - PADDLE_WIDTH_PX) / 2,
y: canvas.height - PADDLE_HEIGHT_PX
}

var Brick = function() { 
canvas.width / 30 = x;
canvas.height / 50 = y;
var bricks(750);
var location_X(750);
var location_Y(750);
for (int b = 0; b <= 749; b++)
{
    if (b == 0)
    {
        location_X[b] = 0;
        location_Y[b] = 0;
    }
    if (b != 0)
    {
        while (b <= 29)
        {
            location_X[b] = (location_X[b - 1]) + Brick.x;
        }
        while (b <= 49)
        {
            location_Y[b] = (location_Y[b - 1]) + Brick.y;
        }
    }
    switch (b % 10) {
    case 0:
        bricks[b] = firebrick;
    break;
    case 1:
        bricks[b] = gold;
    break;
    case 2:
        bricks[b] = yellow;
    break;
    case 3:
        bricks[b] = green;
    break;
    case 4:
        bricks[b] = fuschia;
    break;
    case 6:
        bricks[b] = palevioletred;
    break;
    case 7:
        bricks[b] = goldenrod;
    break;
    case 8:
        bricks[b] = turquoise;
    break;
    case 9:
        bricks[b] = white;
    break;
    default:
        bricks[b] = thistle;
    break;
    }
}
} 
}

var keysDown = {};
window.addEventListener("keydown",function(e) {
keysDown[e.keyCode] = true;
});
window.addEventListener("keyup",function(e) {
delete keysDown[e.keyCode];
});


function render() {
  //clear the canvas
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height)
  // draw the ball
  ctx.fillStyle = "white";
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(ball.x, ball.y, ball.radius, 0, Math.PI * 2);
  ctx.closePath();
  ctx.fill();
  ctx.beginPath();
  //ctx.fillStyle = "red";
  /*ctx.moveTo(canvas.width - (2*paddle.x), canvas.height - (2*paddle.y));
  /*ctx.lineTo(canvas.width / 2, canvas.height - (canvas.height / 12.5));
  ctx.lineTo(canvas.width / 1.35, canvas.height - (canvas.height / 27.5));
  ctx.moveTo(canvas.width / 2, canvas.height - (canvas.height / 27.5));
  ctx.lineTo(canvas.width / 2, canvas.height - (canvas.height / 12.5));
  ctx.lineTo(canvas.width / 1.35, canvas.height - (canvas.height / 27.5));
  ctx.fill();
  ctx.closePath();*/
  /*ctx.lineTo(canvas.width - (2*paddle.x), canvas.height - paddle.y);
  ctx.moveTo(canvas.width - paddle.x, canvas.height - paddle.y);
  ctx.lineTo(canvas.width - paddle.x, canvas.height - (2*paddle.y));
  ctx.lineTo(canvas.width - (2*paddle.x), (canvas.height -paddle.y));*/
  ctx.fillRect(paddle.x, paddle.y, PADDLE_WIDTH_PX, PADDLE_HEIGHT_PX);
  for (int b = 0; b <= 749; b++)
{
    ctx.fillStyle = "Brick.bricks[b]";
    ctx.fillRect(Bricks.location_X[b], Bricks.location_Y[b], Bricks.x, Bricks.y);
}
  /*ctx.closePath();
  ctx.fill();*/
}

function update(elapsed) {
  //update the ball position according to the elapsed time
  ball.y += ball.ySpeed * elapsed;
  ball.x += ball.xSpeed * elapsed;
  /*paddle.TopRight += paddle.speed * elapsed;
  paddle.BottomLeft += paddle.speed * elapsed;
  paddle.RightSide += paddle.speed * elapsed;
  paddle.LeftSide += paddle.speed * elapsed;
  paddle.TopSide += paddle.speed * elapsed;
  paddle.BottomSide += paddle.speed * elapsed;*/
  /*paddle.x += paddle.xSpeed * elapsed;
  paddle.y += paddle.xSpeed * elapsed;*/

  //bounce the ball of all edges
if (37 in keysDown && paddle.x > 0)
  paddle.x -= PADDLE_SPEED * elapsed;
if (39 in keysDown && paddle.x + PADDLE_WIDTH_PX < canvas.width)
  paddle.x += PADDLE_SPEED * elapsed;

  if (ball.x+(ball.x/7) >= canvas.width) {
    ball.x -= 5;
    ball.xSpeed *= -1;
  }
  if (ball.x-(ball.x/7) <= 0) {
      ball.x += 5;
      ball.xSpeed *= -1;
  }
  if (ball.y+(ball.y/100) <= 0) {
    ball.y += 5;
    ball.ySpeed *= -1;
  }
  if (ball.y+(ball.y/3) >= canvas.height) {
    ball.y -= 5;
    ball.ySpeed *= -1;
    }

  /*
  The problem here is that sometimes the ball gets 'stuck' to an edge.

  This can occur when the ball passes beyond an edge in a frame when the
  elapsed time is relatively large. In some cases, when the elapsed time in the
  next frame is relatively short, the ball doesn't reach the edge to get back
  into play. This results in another flip of the velocity and the ball becomes
  'trapped' on the edge.

  e.g.
  xSpeed = -500, x = 10, elapsed = 0.2 => xSpeed = 500, x = -90 (xMovement = -100)
  xSpeed = 500, x = -90, elapsed = 0.1 => xSpeed = -500, x = -40 (xMovement = +50)
  xSpeed = -500, x = -40, elapsed = 0.1 => xSpeed = 500, x = -40 (xMovement = -50)
  and so on ...until a larger elapsed time occurs in the right direction

  The fix for this is to move the ball to the edge when the velocity is flipped.
  */
}

var previous;
function run(timestamp) {
  if (!previous) previous = timestamp;          //start with no elapsed time
  var elapsed = (timestamp - previous) / 1000;  //work out the elapsed time
  update(elapsed);                              //update the game with the elapsed time
  render();                                     //render the scene
  previous = timestamp;                         //set the (globally defined) previous timestamp ready for next time
  window.requestAnimationFrame(run);            //ask browser to call this function again, when it's ready
}

//trigger the game loop
window.requestAnimationFrame(run);
```

Thanks for taking the time to read this,

--ConfusedStudent

Comment: Thankyou! I've looked in the 'array' section for MDN and I can't find where I went wrong - could you clarify?

Answer (score 0):

The first thing that jumps out is there are a lot of syntax errors (ex. some variable assignments are backwards), so your script isn't going to execute.  If you run your JavaScript through [JSLint](http://jslint.com/), you'll see several errors that need to be fixed first.  If you clean up those errors and update your post, someone will be able to help you more easily.